# Is there any difference between an edge/blade guard/protector and a sheath?

Tags: word-meaning, synonyms

I wonder whether there exists any difference between an edge/blade guard/protector and a sheath.

I'm trying to name the following item:

[image]

Comment: The word ***sheath*** has a long history of being used to refer to a case attached to a belt, for holding a *[bladed] **weapon*** (knife, sword, dagger,...) carried about the person (cf ***holster*** for guns). So it's quite possible many people would like to avoid those connotations in the context of culinary equipment such as kitchen knives. That's probaby at least *part* of the justification for "knife guard", "edge protector", etc.

Comment: ...personally, I might *slightly* distinguish "blade guard" (that stops *me* accidentally cutting myself) from "edge protctor" (prevents damage to the edge of the blade). But essentially they're the same thing - it's just a matter of which aspect you want to emphasise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is usually called a "sheath" or "knife guard".

And no they all have the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Since the object in the picture clearly encloses the whole of the blade and so it qualified as a sheath. The question then is whether any of the the other options is appropriate. I would have said that an edge guard or protector was something which just fitted over the edge to protect it or the user from harm but which does not cover the whole blade. A blade guard could have wider application than edge guard and would seem correct for the particular object shown. You do see edge guards on other sharp objects as well like chisels, saws and scraper blades.